# Where to put a tools branch in git?

Tags: git, git-branch, branching-and-merging

I would like to ask for some advice about a good git branch strategy.

**The situation**

I have a repository with a master branch. From it, a developer branch has started. This developer branch has several commits. From the developer branch several other branches have started.

Eventually I suppose all these branches will be merged or discarded and ultimately in the future I suppose everything will merge into the master branch but not yet

**what I want to do**

Now, I have to incorporate into the repository a few shell scripts into a "tools" folder for anyone to use.

To do this I am thinking of creating a new branch, adding the code and committing.

**My question is, *where* in the git tree should be best to start this branch ?**

I have thought of creating a branch directly in master and then merging it to master and then rebasing develop and all the others.

On the other hand perhaps I should create this on top of develop, merge it and just rebase the children branches.

What is the standard or most common approach to this?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a branch `tools`, develop and test the tools, then merge to `master`. Whoever needs them can rebase or cherry-pick from there.

Frequent* rebases from feature branches onto `master` is a good practice anyway. It makes the final merge less painful and dangerous.

<sub>* - daily, at worst weekly</sub>

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, there is no 'standard' or 'most common' approach doing this.

An intuitive way would be to do it with a branch created from **master**, do your changes and addings of your common stuff there.
Every developer branch shall do a merge and rebase.

The master is the master